# C++ std::vector<std::shared_ptr>

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the vector of shared_ptrS. My code is :

```
//--------scoala.h--------

class Scoala
{
public:
    Scoala(std::string );

    int adaugaElev(std::shared_ptr<Elev> elev);
private:

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr <Elev>> __elevi;
};



//-----------scoala.cpp-----------------------------

int Scoala::adaugaElev(std::shared_ptr<Elev> elev)
{
    __elevi.push_back(elev);
    return __elevi.size() - 1;
}
```

I run it  and I got this  "Unhandled exception at 0x0137b559 in elev.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccd0c". What's wrong ?

Comment: Apart from anything else the name `__elevi` is illegal in C++ user code, as are all names that contain double underscores or start with an underscore and an uppercase letter. You also need to post the code that calls your function, and to investigate the concept of references.

Comment: Please use the `{ }` button in the text editor to format your code. You get better answers when your question is *readable*.

Comment: Yes, nothing weird. Have a look at your shared_ptr initialisation.

Comment: Are you using a C++1x compiler ? Also checking the Scoala object pointer would be a good idea here.

Comment: Can you use a debugger to find out exactly where the access violation takes place? Also trying to scale the program down to a minimalistic example, proving the error often helps. In your example it is unclear how `Scoala::aduagaElev` is called, which is relevant to find the error.

Comment: How are you creating the `shared_ptr`'s? The location in the message looks very much like an uninitialized pointer plus an offset.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your elev object passed into adaugaElev was either not allocated, or was somehow unallocated (reference count hit zero in the shared_ptr) - you'll need to post more code showing how you allocate your Elev object to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Run your program under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) - it will help illuminate where the problems are.

Comment: Thinking is a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Using double underscore prefixed names is undefined behaviour in C++. In addition, Elev could be busted for various reasons, and I'd trace it's origin.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure it literally is undefined behaviour.